# É possível fazer engenharia reversa de aplicativos em React Native?

Tags: javascript, segurança, react-native, engenharia-reversa

Estou trabalhando no meu TCC e estou pesquisando sobre engenharia reversa, e como trabalho com react native, queria saber se é possível eu tendo um APK pegar o código javascript dele.

Eu sei que usando o apktool e o d2j-dex2jar eu consigo o código em java e consigo ver que o APK está usando react native se eu encontrar a pasta **/com/facebook/react/**, mas queria saber se é possível encontrar o código JS.

Comment: Tente isso [APK Decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk Talvez possa te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O código JS é embarcado no APK como um asset.

Basta descompactar o APK** e irá encontrar o arquivo `index.android.bundle` na pasta `assets`.
O arquivo `index.android.bundle` é o arquivo JS que contem o seu código.

** o APK é um arquivo zip. Para descompactar basta usar um programa que faça `unzip`